# Saving data as java object after uploading file and text fields using angularjs

Tags: java, angularjs, ng-file-upload

I am using ng-fileupload and trying to capture two custom text fields. My ui code is similar to http://jsfiddle.net/danialfarid/maqbzv15/1118/

The request send using fiddle is as follows:

```
POST http://localhost:8081/test-ui/api/uploadXml HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8081
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 547
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin: http://localhost:8081
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.110 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryziDfCPZA550MEOaA
Referer: http://localhost:8081/ec-ui/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8

------WebKitFormBoundaryziDfCPZA550MEOaA
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="userName"

hello
------WebKitFormBoundaryziDfCPZA550MEOaA
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="xmlFileName"

abc.xml
------WebKitFormBoundaryziDfCPZA550MEOaA
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="note.xml"
Content-Type: text/xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<note>
    <to>Tove</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
------WebKitFormBoundaryziDfCPZA550MEOaA--
```

I want to capture the fields and file in a java object. I was trying to use something like this

```
    @Path("/uploadXML")
    @POST
    @Consumes("multipart/form-data")
    @Produces(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public FileUploadResponse handleFileUpload(MultipartFormDataInput input) throws Exception {
 Map<String, List<InputPart>> formParts = input.getFormDataMap();
        List<InputPart> inFileNames = formParts.get("xmlFileName");
        List<InputPart> inUserNames = formParts.get("userName");
        List<InputPart> inFiles = formParts.get("file");

}
```

however, i am not being able to figure out how to get the text values of fields i.e userName=hello, xmlFileName=abc.xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this answer to similar problem
http://howtodoinjava.com/resteasy/jax-rs-resteasy-file-upload-html-form-example/